# How is "batch_size" in joblib.Parallel different from "chunk_size" in multiprocessing.Pool.map?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, joblib

There are two things that are not clear to me as to how "batch_size" option in joblib works. The following code can capture my concern.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time
import numpy as np
import sys

def doubler(number):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    return number * 2

def main(idx,num_proc):
    num_elements = 1000
    num_iter     = 2

    # multiprocessing    
    if idx == 0:
        x = np.arange(1,num_elements,1,int)
        print("Module: multiprocessing.Pool")
        chunk = int(num_elements/(4*num_proc))
        pool = Pool(processes=num_proc)
        for iter in range(num_iter):
            t1 = time.time()
            result = pool.map(doubler, x, chunk)
            print("num_proc =", num_proc, ", runtime = ", time.time() - t1)
        pool.close()    

    # joblib
    elif idx == 1:
        print("Module: joblib.Parallel")
#        chunk = int(num_elements/(4*num_proc))
        with Parallel(n_jobs=num_proc,backend='multiprocessing',batch_size='auto',prefer='processes',max_nbytes=None,verbose=10) as parallel:
#        with Parallel(n_jobs=num_proc,backend='multiprocessing',batch_size=chunk,pre_dispatch=chunk,prefer='processes',max_nbytes=None,verbose=20) as parallel:
            for iter in range(num_iter):    
                t1 = time.time()
                result = parallel(delayed(doubler)(x) for x in np.arange(1,num_elements,1,int))        
                print("num_proc =", num_proc, ", runtime = ", time.time() - t1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    idx = 1
    num_proc = 2
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        idx = int(sys.argv[1])
        num_proc = int(sys.argv[2])
    main(idx,num_proc)
```

First, The code with idx=1 shows the role of batch_size in joblib. When I run the program, a default setting must be pre_dispath=4 and batch_size='auto' with the initial size of 1. As the verbose message prints out, it starts with batch_size=1 and then it switches to batch_size=2 after 12 tasks and then to batch_size=26 after 20 tasks, and overall, the first run took 5.7 sec.

```
Module: joblib.Parallel
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Using backend MultiprocessingBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   2 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   3 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   4 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   5 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   6 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   7 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   8 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   9 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Batch computation too fast (0.1690s.) Setting batch_size=2.
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  10 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  11 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  12 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  14 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Batch computation too fast (0.0301s.) Setting batch_size=26.
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  16 tasks      | elapsed:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  18 tasks      | elapsed:    0.5s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  20 tasks      | elapsed:    0.5s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  46 tasks      | elapsed:    0.7s
...
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done 999 out of 999 | elapsed:    5.6s finished
num_proc = 2 , runtime =  5.668241024017334
```

Now, reusing the same pools, I run the same function again.

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   4 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  30 tasks      | elapsed:    0.2s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  56 tasks      | elapsed:    0.5s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  82 tasks      | elapsed:    0.8s
...
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done 999 tasks      | elapsed:   10.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done 999 out of 999 | elapsed:   10.3s finished
num_proc = 2 , runtime =  10.353703498840332
```

It is clear from the message that pre_dispatch = 4 and batch_size = 26. This 26 batch_size comes from the previous program run. However, the second run took 10.4 sec, which is twice slower than the first run.

My first question is:
**1. Is there a way to get around this "batch_size" overwrite problem, other than "NOT" reusing the pools?**

---

Secondly, I was trying to understand any overhead in joblib.Parallel (if any) compared to multiprocessing.Pool. To this end, I changed the code by adding

```
chunk = int(num_elements/(4*num_proc))
with Parallel(n_jobs=num_proc,backend='multiprocessing',batch_size=chunk,pre_dispatch=chunk,prefer='processes',max_nbytes=None,verbose=20) as parallel:
```

It is my understanding (correct me if I am wrong) that the default chunk_size in multirprocessing.Pool.map is num_elements/(4*num_proc). However, the results show that joblib.Parallel takes 10.6 sec, while multiprocessing.Pool takes 5.4 sec (you can check this by setting idx=0).

Then, my second question is:
**2. How is "batch_size" in joblib different from "chunk_size" in multiprocessing?**

(Please note that I am using python 3.6.5 and joblib 0.12.5)